# Convert 64-Bit Binary floating-point number into a base 10 decimal

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I have a task to convert a **64-bit binary floating-point number** into a **base 10 decimal**.
An example here:

**Input:**
64-bit binary floating-point number: 0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000

**Output:**
Base 10 Decimal: 3.14

what I know here, first character is a sign = 0 (positive) , 1(negative).
Next 11 bits represent the exponent, and the rests are Mantissa.

My problem is I don't know the math equation or the math solution to convert it. I am going to solve this task using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation.  As you already stated, the main parts are:

```
- sign     = 0
- exponent = 10000000000
- mantissa = 1001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
```

Since all mantissa values are shifted left (normalized) until the first bit is a `1`, that bit can be implied.  So the actual mantissa prefixed with a `1`, the value would be

```
- mantissa = 11001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
```

The base offset for the exponent is `1023`. The exponent above is `1024` so the exponent would be `1` + an additional `1` for the implied bit.

`.11 x 2`<sup>`2`</sup>
So the whole number part would be binary `11` or decimal `3`.

```
double whole = 3;
```

The rest of the mantissa is the fractional part and starts where the whole number stopped.

```
fraction = 001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
```

so given a string of bits as above, the fractional part can be added to the whole by dividing each successive bit by ever increasing powers of 2. `(e.g. 0/2 + 0/4 + 1/8 +  etc)`

```
double div = 1.;
for (char c : fract.toCharArray()) {
     div*=2.;
     whole += (c-'0')/div;
}
System.out.println(whole);
```

prints

```
3.141592653589793
```

Note:  The above was cheating somewhat in that it used a double to compute the fractional part.  There are more involved methods to emulate floating point math but the purpose here was to demonstrate extracting the bit fields to create a double value.  If I were doing this I would use the methods described in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks man. It really helped me a lot.The solution was from scratch. I will never forget this concept in future

Answer (score 1):

`Double.longBitsToDouble(long)` takes a 64-bit long and converts it to a floating point double, which you can then print.

Given that, you can just use `Long.parseLong(binary, 2)` to convert a string of 0s and 1s to a long, and then use that method to get a floating point value.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. But it gives me error if i make the sign bit as 1(Negative). _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1100000000010000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101" under radix 2_

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need `new BigInteger(str, 2).longValue()` instead of Long.parseLong.

Comment: You could use `Long.parseUnsignedLong(str, 2)` - this works for "0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000" and for "1100000000010000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101"

Answer (score 1):

Convert the binary into a `long` value - you can use `Long.parseLong(text, 2)` for that if you've got the binary value as a string... and then `Double.longBitsToDouble` to perform the conversion to a `double`. For example:

```java
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String text = "0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000";
      long parsedAsLong = Long.parseLong(text, 2);
      double converted = Double.longBitsToDouble(parsedAsLong);
      System.out.println(converted);
  }

}
```

Comment: This code gives me an error if make sign as 1 (Negative ). _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1100000000010000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101" under radix 2_

Comment: Thanks man. I got the answers. Thanks for your codes and helps!